# How to Dynamically fetch a custom element and use it

Tags: javascript, web-component

I want to be able to have an event that calls an asynchronous function that (1) fetches a simple web component and (2) adds the customElement to a container (div id).

Using the fetch API, I haven't had any success. Among a lot of tests I tried to convert "result.text()" to HTML with new DOMParser and a [Object HTML] appears in the targeted container or I tried to convert "result.text()" to a function and I get [Object Promise]...

This is currently my load function

```
async function load(){
    var object = fetch("./src/pages/product.js")
            .then(result => result.text())
            .then(obj => new Function(obj))
            .then(t => console.log(t));
    container.innerHTML = object;
}
```

This is my customElement:

```
class MyTest extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()

        const pElem = document.createElement("p");
        pElem.textContent = "Hello from my-test component";

        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(pElem);
    }

}

customElements.define("my-test", MyTest);
```

The expected result is the display of "Hello from my-test component" in the container. How would you do it?

Your help will be very appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Typo...

When you create a customElement like this: (shortened way, thanks to Danny)

```
customElements.define("my-test", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
           .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
           .textContent = "Hello from my-test component";
    }
})
```

You can asynchronously call it this way:

```
async function load() {
    const imported = await import("./pages/product.js");
    const customElem = document.createElement("my-test"); 
    container.appendChild(customElem);
}
```

I hope this will someone!

Comment: If your product.js only *defines* the element you don't have to wait; ``createElement`` will create an *unknown* element. The moment ``define("my-test"`` runs it will **upgrade** all ``<my-test>`` elements in the page.

Comment: oh, ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your element code (in product.js I presume)

You need to properly load that JavaScript file

All answers here: 
[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146)
(with 4400+ upvotes, give him one more)

---

You *can* shorten your code:

```
customElements.define("my-test", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        const pElem = document.createElement("p");
        pElem.textContent = "Hello from my-test component";
        super().attachShadow({mode: "open"}).append(pElem);
    }
})
```

- because `super` returns `this`
- and `attachShadow` both sets and returns `this.shadowRoot`
- `append` is shorter and can take multiple parameters, but does not return anything
- `appendChild` returns the inserted element, so you could write:

```
customElements.define("my-test", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
      .textContent = "Hello from my-test component";
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I have read the linked page and, except the FetchInject, it does not seem to answer my question. I try to do it with native/direct code, to learn Javascript.
Thank you fo shortening my code. I think the first line should read `customElement.define("my-test", class extends HTMLElement {`

Comment: For now I'm heading toward something (does work yet) like this:
`async function load() {
  const imported = await import("./pages/product.js");
  customElements.define("my-test", imp.MyTest());
  const cutomElem = document.createElement("my-test");
  container.appendChild(customElem);
}`
Something doesn't work in line 3 (custmonEl....). Still searching, any help is welcome!